# Access HDFS from eclipse in windows

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is it possible to access the HDFS from eclipse which is in windows and retrieve the folder content in from hdfs to eclipse and store it in list.

Comment: Yes. All of Hadoop is just a Java library. What have you tried?

Comment: I am connecting to remote system with jsch library and then run hdfs commands like   ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command) where command is hdfs dfs -ls /abc/ope/files

Comment: Okay, or you could just install Hadoop locally and configure it to talk to the remote system